# anyway i can recover tezos wallet password programatically or verify that password given is correct for a tezos account

Tags: wallets

I am trying to create some sort of system in high level language (like C#) to recover a wallet password. Also trying to authenticate from known password with wallet (to certify that wallet provided credentials are correct)
Is there any possibility in tezos?

Comment: What do you mean by "recover wallet password"? Are you trying to enter something and have a tool spit out the password that was used? Are you referring to a password used to encrypt something like a keystore file, or a password used as an optional word at the end of a seed phrase?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question.

You can have a look at this [Java SDK](https://github.com/TezosRio/TezosJ_SDK/blob/master/tezosj_android/src/main/java/milfont/com/tezosj_android/model/TezosWallet.java#L255), it should be similar to `C#`.

Comment: is there any method there in this java sdk for password confirmation/retrieval? this is mostly looks like a account creation related thing which i have also found in netezos

Answer (score 0):

Answering the second part about confirming a wallet is correct (while waiting for an update on the first part, via comment). There is not any single function that can answer "is this wallet correct" for a user. This is not a Tezos thing, this is a blockchain thing. Any combination of valid seed words will produce a wallet, its up to the user to determine if that is the correct one. There are a few things you can do to help the user determine if what they are doing is correct

1. There are tools that generate Mnemonics (seed phrases), most commonly these tools have a method to validate that a mnemonic matches the spec. E.g. Here is one using the language Swift for iOS: https://github.com/keefertaylor/MnemonicKit (I don't know about Java or C#, but they should have "validate" methods). This can be used to let a user know if they are entering a valid Mnemonic
2. Display the TZ address. After they enter a Mnemonic, optional password, or upload a keystore file etc, whatever way your app will work. Present them with the generated TZ address. If they are importing a wallet they already own, most users will recognise the first/last few characters
3. Going a step further, after generating the TZ address you could fetch the account balance and display that along side the address. Be careful with this, and make sure you don't build something that could be abused by flooding a server with requests

Comment: My problem is to validate Wallet password is correct or not? Suppose i have a simple windows form utility which will take wallet email and password (or may be wallet public key address as well). i want to check whether this information is correct ornot using some high level language

Comment: @KamranShahid wallets don't use email and password. Wallets use a seed phrase and there are 2 different types of passwords that are optional (mentioned in my comment on your question above). The process is, as i've mentioned in my answer, you ask the user for their information, you do some basic tests to see does that data match a spec, create a wallet from that data and show them the address. The user decides if its correct or not. I think you may need to download a bunch of wallet apps and use some websites to see how things work

Comment: https://github.com/baking-bad/netezos/issues/49 it have detail regarding what i am trying

Comment: @KamranShahid I think you've made a fundamental misunderstanding about how blockchain wallets work and what those email addresses were used for. The email address for ICO wallets was a 1 time only thing. Tezos didn't exist when people signed up for the ICO, so they couldn't be given normal wallets. They had to use some other system to send the coins to people, until the network existed. So they used email and did something special. Once the network was up and running, those people followed instructions with their email and got their coins, they were supposed to ...

Comment: @KamranShahid transfer the funds into a normal wallet so that they could be recovered next time. This process of using emails is not how new wallets are created, this system will likely never be used again. It is only for old legacy wallets. As you can see from the link you have yourself linked too, the only way to "recover" the password, is to simply brute force it (try every possible password) until a TZ address is generated that matches the TZ address in the ICO file

Comment: @KamranShahid for normal wallets (that didn't go through ICO), the user must provide the seed phrase and an optional password. If the user has forgotten the optional password, the only thing that could be done is ask them for the TZ address and brute force the password until one matches. This could take an incredibly long time. All wallets are "offline" there is no server that you can ask to reset a password, or find your seed phrase. Users MUST remember them or back them up ... or the funds are lost. Brute forcing is the only option outside of that

Comment: Thanks @Simon. Can i do some verification of a wallet address via seed phrase only or with password. my current research is only around the verification part?

Comment: @KamranShahid I have answered this exact question in my answer above. The only thing you can verify is if the seed phrase matches the spec

Comment: i had one .net library of netezos where i have posted a question https://github.com/baking-bad/netezos/issues/49 there were some more insight iwere able to get from it as well.thanks